# Reset the MiKTeX options/package manager/update button in WinEdt

Tags: winedt

This is a minor thing, but I would like to reset the MiKTeX options/package manager/update button in WinEdt 9.0 so its default is to update MiKTeX.  The other bottons that have drop-down lists will reset to whatever I last chose in the list. But I can't get this one to move away from a default of MiKTeX options.

I have looked around in Options -> Execution Modes and places like that but have not found a way.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toolbar can contain various types of buttons. For dropdown buttons you have four choices:

> - Type 5: Drop-down menu – clicking on the button only displays this menu.
> - Type 6: Drop-down menu – button has a fixed menu item associated with it.
> - Type 7: Drop-down menu – choosing any menu item associates this item with the button and then executes it.
> - Type 8: Drop-down menu – choosing any menu item associates this item with the button without executing it.

---

By default, that button is a Type 6.

You have two options:

1. Leave it as Type 6 and change the default button from "MiKTeX Options" to "MiKTeX Update Wizard".
2. Change its type from 6 to 7 or 8.

---

To act on this, do the following:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]

   and double-click the "Toolbar" item (`Toolbar.ini` gets opened)
2. In this file locate the lines

   ```
     BUTTON="MiKTeX_Options"
       TYPE=6
   ```

   If you want to follow the first option simply change the line

   ```
     BUTTON="MiKTeX_Options"
   ```

   to

   ```
     BUTTON="MiKTeX_Update_Wizard"
   ```

   Instead, if you want to follow the second option, change the line

   ```
       TYPE=6
   ```

   to

   ```
       TYPE=7
   ```

   or

   ```
       TYPE=8
   ```

   depending on your choice of button.
3. At this point, press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file. That's it.